# Android Database backups

Tags: android

This is simply a question of best practices.

I would like to know which is a better way to manage db backups. The first option is to use the Android Backup Service. Now this initially seemed like a great idea, but apparently isn't supported by all phones/couriers? Also, the user would have had to enable backups in the phone's settings.

The other option is to simply copy the SQLite file to the SD card and vice versa. But this would mean anyone could pretty much open and use my database without my permission. It would also mean the user would lose all data if the SD card became corrupted or the phone was lost.

Any ideas and suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- export the database as CSV/XML/JSON and have add import functionality
  to your app
- have your own server, and allow users to backup to it (you'll need to use SSL and some form of user authentication)
- compress the db file and copy it to the SD card.

As for protecting it, how sensitive is it? You could have the user enter a password when they backup, and encrypt it if you feel you need to protect is.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. So you feel that managing the backup yourself insteand of the BackupAgent is the better idea. Before I get into it really, I want to pick out a strategy.

The data isn't that personal or sensitive. It's a database of tasks, budget items, contacts (ok.. this might be an issue), etc.